# Derivative: does it have a quotition interpretation or a partition one

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Assume that we have a linear function:
$$
y=ax
$$
Here, the slope is $a.$ What interpretation does the slope have?
Is it a) For each unit of $x,$ $y$ changes be $a$ units (partition)
or b) The change in $y$ is $a$ times bigger than the change in $x.$

Comment: Both those assertions are true, but not the words you are using to describe them. "Quotition" isn't a word in English and "partition" makes little sense in this context.

Comment: @EthanBolker OK. When thinking of derivatives, which one is more apt?

Comment: Neither makes sense.

Comment: I mean not the words, but the interpretation. Is a better thought of as the ratio of dy to dx, or the effect of a unit increase in x on y.

Comment: Both interpretations are correct. Which is better depends on context. in general, it's  good to have several ways to think of any piece of mathematics.

Comment: Thank you, @EthanBolker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at it both ways, those are intuitive ways to think of derivatives of slopes.

However, if you look at it from the derivative's origins of creation, the derivative of a function checks how much the function has changed in it's *y* value in comparison to the distance it traveled in the *x* axis.
That's why a derivate can be written as "*dy/dx*" - it checks the ratio between the change of *y* and *x* in a small distance (the "*d*" is short for Delta).

If you look at that distance as units, interpretation A is more accurate to the nature of derivatives.